# Using button to change PageViewController crashes app on last page

Tags: swift

I am using buttons to change pagecontroll an it changes but the problem comes when it gets to the last page, the app crashes. This is my code to change the pages

```
func backBtnClicked() {
        if currentIndex > 0 {
            currentIndex -= 1
        }
        if currentIndex < 1 {
            backBtn.isHidden = true
        }
        if currentIndex >= 0 {
            nextBtn.setTitle("Next", for: .normal)
            let startingViewController: TableVC? = viewControllerAtIndex(index: currentIndex)
            let viewControllers = [startingViewController]
            pageController?.setViewControllers(viewControllers as? [UIViewController], direction: .reverse, animated: false)
        }

    }

    @objc func nextBtnClicked() {
        if currentIndex != NSNotFound {
            currentIndex += 1
        }

        if currentIndex == pg.count - 1 {
            //Navigate Outside Pageview controller
            log("lastt")
        } else {


            let startingViewController: TableVC? = viewControllerAtIndex(index: currentIndex)
            let viewControllers = [startingViewController]
            pageController?.setViewControllers(viewControllers as? [UIViewController], direction: .forward, animated: false)
        }

    }
```

This is the error I am getting

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'The number of view controllers
>   provided (0) doesn't match the number required (1) for the requested
>   transition'

any help

Comment: WHy are you checking `NSNotFound `, and are you sure that `pg.count == viewControllerAtIndex.count`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
pageController?.setViewControllers(viewControllers as? [UIViewController], direction: .forward, animated: false)
```

with

```
pageController?.setViewControllers(viewControllers, direction: .forward, animated: false)
```

To be

```
let startingViewController = viewControllerAtIndex(index: currentIndex)!
pageController?.setViewControllers([startingViewController], direction: .forward, animated: false)
```

---

In back press

```
guard currentIndex - 1 >= 0 else { return }
currentIndex -= 1
// get the vc
```

In next press

```
guard currentIndex + 1 < pg.count else { return }
currentIndex  += 1
// get the vc
```

In your current code it appears that this `let startingViewController: TableVC?` returns nil at some point which make this `viewControllers as? [UIViewController]` to be an empty array